# How to determine two discrete functions are the same

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

It is my first day here.

I got a question about how to determine if two discrete functions are the same.

I know for continuous functions if I want to say they are the same. Their domains and their expression must to be the same.

For example,

```
 if x belongs to R (the real number) f(x)=(x+1)^2=g(x)=x^2+2x+1
```

However, 
f(x)=x    domain {1} 
g(x)=1    domain {1}
h(x)=x^2   domain {1}
Are they the same? I know although the expressions are indeed different, the results are the same.

Also, let's say the domain is {0,1,2} f(x) and g(x) are defined in this domain.

f(0)=0, f(1)=1,f(2)=4,
g(x)=x^2, so g(0)=0,g(1)=1,g(2)=4

Are they the same?

Thanks a lot for any possible help.

Btw, could anyone teach me how to do Latex here? The math typing kills me

:)))))

Comment: See the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). As for the mathematics, two functions are the same if their domains are the same and they agree on the result for each argument in their common domain.

Comment: If the domain of both $f$ and of $g$ is, say, $D$, and $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x$ in $D$, then $f=g$.

Comment: so you mean the expression does not matter?